# Vue 3 using vue-i18n separate multiple json files?

Tags: json, internationalization, vuejs3, vite, vue-i18n

This is my folder structure:
[image]

This is my code in plugins/i18n.ts

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import en from '@/locales/en.json'
import kh from '@/locales/kh.json'
import enRecruitment from '@/modules/recruitments/locales/en.json'
import khRecruitment from '@/modules/recruitments/locales/kh.json'

// Merge english locales json files
const enSources = [en, enRecruitment]
const enMessages = enSources.reduce((acc: any, source: any) => {
    for (const key in source) {
        acc[key] = { ...(acc[key] || {}), ...source[key] }
    }
    return acc
}, {})

// Merge khmer locales json files
const khSources = [kh, khRecruitment]
const khMessages = enSources.reduce((acc: any, source: any) => {
    for (const key in source) {
        acc[key] = { ...(acc[key] || {}), ...source[key] }
    }
    return acc
}, {})

// console.log({ enMessages: JSON.stringify(enMessages), khMessages })

const i18n = createI18n({
    legacy: false, // Use Composition API
    locale: 'en', // Default locale
    fallbackLocale: 'en', // Fallback locale if translation not available
    messages: {
        en: enMessages,
        kh: khMessages,
        // Add other language translations here
    },
})

export default i18n
```

**I want to merge locales/en.json with modules/locales/en.json & locales/kh.json with modules/locales/kh.json**

**How to resolve this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import en from '@/locales/en.json'
import kh from '@/locales/kh.json'
import enRecruitment from '@/modules/recruitments/locales/en.json'
import khRecruitment from '@/modules/recruitments/locales/kh.json'

// Merge english locales json files
const enMessages = Object.assign(en, enRecruitment);

// Merge khmer locales json files
const khMessages = Object.assign(kh, khRecruitment);

const i18n = createI18n({
    legacy: false, // Use Composition API
    locale: 'en', // Default locale
    fallbackLocale: 'en', // Fallback locale if translation not available
    messages: {
        en: enMessages,
        kh: khMessages,
        // Add other language translations here
    },
})

export default i18n;
```